# Qt Crash SIGSEGV Fault while dynamically adding widgets to scrollArea (ui->scrollArea->setWidget(...))

Tags: c++, qt, crash

**My Intention**

- I want to create and add a `QWidget` to `scrollArea`. 
   Then
- create and set a `grid layout` for that `QWidget`.
- Then fill up that `grid layout` with `push buttons` each of which
  have a text whose value comes from the input `int* array`.

**Overview of My Code:**
I have a `QDialog` application with a `UI form`. 
In my UI form I have added a `scrollArea` using `QtDesigner`.
In my program when some event happens I call the following function:

```
void View::setUpBatteryTypes(int* array,int size)
{
    QGridLayout* gl=new QGridLayout();
    QWidget *viewport = new QWidget;
    viewport->setLayout(gl);
    qDebug()<<"debug test 1";
    ui->scrollArea->setWidget(viewport); //crashes here in 2nd call of func
    qDebug()<<"debug test 2";

    QPushButton* pushButtons=new QPushButton[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        pushButtons[i].setText(QVariant(array[i]).toString());
        pushButtons[i].setMinimumSize(200,100);
        pushButtons[i].setMaximumSize(400,200);
        pushButtons[i].setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170,170,197);");
        gl->addWidget(&pushButtons[i],(int)floor(i/3),i%3);

    }  
}
```

**Problem**
My problem is that when I call the function `setUpBatteryTypes` for the first time in my app everything is ok and the function does what I intend to do. However, when the function is called for the second time in my app it crashes in the commented line in between the two qDebug() statements.

---

Here is my code
**dialog.h**

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
public:
    void setUpBatteryTypes(int*,int);
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

**dialog.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPushButton>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::setUpBatteryTypes(int* array,int size)
{

    QGridLayout* gl=new QGridLayout();
    QWidget *viewport = new QWidget;
    viewport->setLayout(gl );
    qDebug()<<"debug test 1";
    qDebug()<<ui->scrollArea->children();
    ui->scrollArea->setWidget(viewport);
    qDebug()<<ui->scrollArea->children();
    qDebug()<<"debug test 2";

    QPushButton* pushButtons=new QPushButton[size];

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        pushButtons[i].setText(QVariant(array[i]).toString());
        pushButtons[i].setMinimumSize(200,100);
        pushButtons[i].setMaximumSize(400,200);
        pushButtons[i].setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(170,170,197);");
        gl->addWidget(&pushButtons[i],(int)floor(i/3),i%3);
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog* w=new Dialog();
    w->show();
    int size=4;
    int* array=new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        array[i]=i;
    }

    w->setUpBatteryTypes(array,size);
    w->setUpBatteryTypes(array,size);

    return a.exec();
}
```

**dialog.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
     <property name="widgetResizable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>380</width>
        <height>280</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

I debugged my code and it shows a SIGSEGV fault.
I also updated the question title accordingly.

Comment: `ui->scrollArea` or `ui` is NULL or underfined. Put the rest of your code. Or simply go through it again and find where you could lost defined values after first call.

Comment: Do you have a crash message ? Did you try to debug step by step, checking the variables ?

Comment: @llya crash message The program has unexpectedly finished.
I debugged step by step and found where it crashed.

Comment: I edited my question and included my code.

Answer (score 0):

You added address of local objects as paramater.

Here you create an object array, which are local to this function

```
QPushButton* pushButtons=new QPushButton[size];
```

And here you pass their address, which will be eventually invalid after function has ended

```
gl->addWidget(&pushButtons[i],(int)floor(i/3),i%3);
```

Edit:
Try

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    QPushButton* pushButtons=new QPushButton;
    pushButtons=new QPushbutton;
    ...
    gl->addWidget(pushButtons,(int)floor(i/3),i%3);
}
```